# Changing names (version numbers) in nested folders with find and mv

Tags: bash, shell

TL;DR: I want all the 2.6s to say 2.7

```
     lib
     └── python2.6
        └── site-packages
            ├── x
            │   ├── x.py
            │   ├── x.pyc
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   └── test
            │       ├── __init__.py
            │       └── __init__.pyc
            └── x-0.2.0-py2.6.egg-info
                ├── dependency_links.txt
                ├── entry_points.txt
                ├── PKG-INFO
                ├── requires.txt
                ├── SOURCES.txt
                └── top_level.txt
```

What I've tried:

```
find . -type d -name "*2.6*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/2.6/2.7}"' -- {} \;
```

Obviously this doesn't work because it sees the main folder, moves that, and then sees the nested folder and tries to move it, but it no longer exists in that spot and says `no such file or directory`

Is there a good way to do nested find and moves? In this case, I can just run the command twice and that would technically work, but it feels dirty.

Also, I know this could screw up the versioning of the package, or that I could do

```
find . -type d -name "*python2.6*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/2.6/2.7}"' -- {} \; 
find . -type d -name "*py2.6*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/2.6/2.7}"' -- {} \;
```

But I'm more interested in learning if bash has a method to solve this in general than how to deal with this narrow scenario.

Comment: Just asking: you're not worried about the _contents_ of the files in those folders having relative links that depend upon the name?

Comment: Not unless you know things about python modules that I have yet to discover.

Comment: [PEP-314](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/) indicates version shall be encoded in the package information.

Comment: Also, on what OS do you want to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure that version refers to the package version (0.2.0), not the python version. Basically, I have Centos6 boxes and a script designed to work in python2.7. I have a weird version of python2.7 installed that the system doesn't know about (since I was told that 2.7 breaks centos6 if you install it like you'd expect), so I'm making this with a terrible kludge of `bdist` and a custom spec file and manually running `rpmbuild`

Comment: I was thinking `Requires-Python: ">=2.7"` for example. But, nevertheless, I get your aim here. Working on a few solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go depth first and substitute only in the basename:

```
find  lib -depth -type d -name "*2.6*" -exec \ 
      bash -c 'basename="${1##*/}" && mv "$1" "${1%/*}/${basename/2.6/2.7}"' -- {} \;
```

If you run it with an `echo` as:

```
find  lib -depth -type d -name "*2.6*" -exec \
      bash -c 'bn="${1##*/}" && echo mv "$1" "${1%/*}/${bn/2.6/2.7}"' -- {} \;
```

on a tree created with:

```
mkdir -p lib/python2.6/site-packages/{x/test,x-0.20-py2.6.egg-info}
```

i.e., on:

```
lib/
└── python2.6
    └── site-packages
        ├── x
        │   └── test
        └── x-0.20-py2.6.egg-info
```

You get:

```
mv lib/python2.6/site-packages/x-0.20-py2.6.egg-info lib/python2.6/site-packages/x-0.20-py2.7.egg-info
mv lib/python2.6 lib/python2.7
```

Remove the echos, and the moves should proceed error-free.